# Group by columns when date ranges are contiguous

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, gaps-and-islands

I have data in a format like this:

```
DECLARE @WidgetPrice TABLE (WidgetPriceId BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1), WidgitId INT, Price MONEY, 
    StartEffectiveWhen DATE, EndEffectiveWhen DATE)

INSERT INTO @WidgetPrice(WidgitId, Price, StartEffectiveWhen, EndEffectiveWhen)
VALUES
(100,      21.48, '2020-1-1',         '2021-8-5'),
(100,      19.34, '2021-8-6',         '2021-12-31'),
(100,      19.34, '2022-1-1',         '2022-12-31'),
(100,      19.34, '2023-1-1',         '2023-1-31'),
-- There is a date gap here (No price from 2023-1-31 to 2023-3-5)
(100,      19.34, '2023-3-5',         '2023-12-31'),
(100,      12.87, '2024-1-1',         '2024-1-31'),
(100,      12.87, '2024-2-1',         '2100-12-31'),
-- Next Widget's prices          
(200,      728.25, '2020-1-1',         '2021-12-31'),
(200,      728.25, '2022-1-1',         '2022-12-31'),
(200,      861.58, '2023-1-1',         '2024-5-21'),
(200,      601.19, '2024-5-22',        '2100-12-31')
```

I need to group by the `WidgetId` and `Price` but only when the dates are contiguous.

So, in my example data, there is a gap in the data between 2023-1-31 and 2023-3-5.  Because there is a gap there, I need to have two entries for the price 19.34.

Here is an image of the data as I would hope to get it:

[image: Desired Data]

The key rows in this output are rows 2 and 3.  It has the same price listed twice because there is a gap in the dates.

I had thought to make a recursive CTE that could look at the `LAG` value for the `StartEffeciveWhen` and `EndEffectiveWhen`, but I could not figure it out.

**Any ideas on how I can build a query that does this?**

NOTE: My actual data is over 113,000,000 rows with a lot more columns.  I have just presented a simplified version for this question.

NOTE 2: I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: 1. Please show us what you tried. 2. Please do not use images, use tabular markdown

Comment: Here's a link for tabular markdown if you need it: https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQLFiddle**:
I put together a SQLFiddle so that you can run this query and adjust it to see different results.  Very useful site: [SQL Fiddle With Answer](https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=65293d23-f9be-44b6-82b0-79866f9aabb7)

**Strategy**:
Instead of focusing on chaining multiple rows togethers, you can focus on finding the edges.  Then you can group by the running total of starting edges.  I'm sure you could shorten this, but this gets the idea across:

1. Use [Lag Windowed Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on Price and Date to find changes.
2. Use Case expression to define edges.
3. Group by [Sum Windowed function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (Running total) of Starts to combine for min and max dates.

```
--Find interesting edges
SELECT 
    WidgitId
    , Price
    , MIN(StartEffectiveWhen) AS StartEffectiveWhen
    , MAX(EndEffectiveWhen) AS EndEffectiveWhen
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUM(i.StartingEdge) OVER (
            PARTITION BY WidgitId ORDER BY StartEffectiveWhen
            ) AS LeadingCount
        , WidgitId
        , Price
        , StartEffectiveWhen
        , EndEffectiveWhen
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN LagPrice != Price
                    OR LagDate != DATEADD(day, - 1, StartEffectiveWhen)
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END AS StartingEdge
            , WidgitId
            , Price
            , StartEffectiveWhen
            , EndEffectiveWhen
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                LAG(price) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY WidgitID ORDER BY StartEffectiveWhen ASC
                    ) AS LagPrice
                , LAG(EndEffectiveWhen) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY WidgitID ORDER BY StartEffectiveWhen ASC
                    ) AS LagDate
                , *
            FROM @WidgetPrice
        ) p
    ) i
) g
GROUP BY g.Price,g.WidgitID,LeadingCount
```

**Output from Query**:

| WidgitId | Price | StartEffectiveWhen | EndEffectiveWhen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 12.87 | 1/1/2024 | 12/31/2100 |
| 100 | 19.34 | 8/6/2021 | 1/31/2023 |
| 100 | 19.34 | 3/5/2023 | 12/31/2023 |
| 100 | 21.48 | 1/1/2020 | 8/5/2021 |
| 200 | 601.19 | 5/22/2024 | 12/31/2100 |
| 200 | 728.25 | 1/1/2020 | 12/31/2022 |
| 200 | 861.58 | 1/1/2023 | 5/21/2024 |

**Alternative sub-query** for those who might want to reduce the number of subqueries:

```
--Find interesting edges
SELECT WidgitId
    ,Price
    ,MIN(StartEffectiveWhen) AS StartEffectiveWhen
    ,MAX(EndEffectiveWhen) AS EndEffectiveWhen
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUM(i.StartingEdge) OVER (
            PARTITION BY WidgitId ORDER BY StartEffectiveWhen
            ) AS LeadingCount
        , WidgitId
        , Price
        , StartEffectiveWhen
        , EndEffectiveWhen
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN LAG(price) OVER (
                            PARTITION BY WidgitID ORDER BY StartEffectiveWhen ASC
                            ) != Price
                    OR LAG(EndEffectiveWhen) OVER (
                            PARTITION BY WidgitID ORDER BY StartEffectiveWhen ASC
                            ) != DATEADD(day, - 1, StartEffectiveWhen)
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END AS StartingEdge
            , WidgitId
            , Price
            , StartEffectiveWhen
            , EndEffectiveWhen
        FROM @WidgetPrice
    ) i
) g
GROUP BY g.Price, g.WidgitID, LeadingCount
```

And here's a [SQL Fiddle for the query with 1 less subquery](https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=263a9cf6-841c-4e93-90d9-030798e02e03)

Comment: Thank you @Dale K for the help with formatting.  I edited it again, not noticing you had already fixed it.

Comment: What is the purpose of `EndingEdge`? It is not used in your query. The `convert(int,..` is also not necessary as the case expression is returning `1` or `0` which is an `int`

Comment: Addressed feedback from Squirrel and Dale K.  I didn't use a CTE because I'm not reusing the same query multiple times.  I feel like a subquery vs CTE is a matter of taste in this case.  I'm open to other feedback in case there's a better way.  Because Windowed functions can't be used in a where clause or group, I feel like I end up with a bunch of nested select statements.  In this case I could combine the innermost query and the next, but it would make for a busy case statement.

Comment: Huh.  I learned coding before SQL, and I never noticed that difference in terminology.  It is an expression in SQL.  Thanks @DaleK.

Comment: It might sound pedantic (and many tutorial sites get it wrong), but the number of people who don't realise you can only return a scalar value (as opposed to conditionally choose an expression) happens because of incorrect use of terminology.

Comment: Good call.  Corrected to Case Expression in answer.  Left incorrect in my comment for context.  :-)

Comment: This is really good.  Your way of thinking on this was impressive.  Thank you for spending time to dig into my problem!  (FYI: I read CTEs better than sub-queries, so converted your answer to use CTEs.  I posted the CTE version just to in case it is useful to other..)

Comment: Found I could remove the ISNULLs.  I originally put them there to make sure that the approach worked.  I tested your CTE approach and it will also work without ISNULLs.  The CTE approach is nice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of Abraham's answer, but re-written using CTEs (I find them easier to read).

The actual awesomeness comes from Abraham's answer, this is just another way to view it.  (Meaning you should up vote Abraham's answer before this.)

```
;WITH ComparableDatesAndPrices AS
(
    -- Make a CTE where we can compare the previous row's price and EndEffecitveWhen with the current row.  
    -- The goal is to be able to see if the price changed, or if there was a gap in dates.
    SELECT  LAG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY WidgitID ORDER BY StartEffectiveWhen ASC) AS LagPrice, 
            LAG(EndEffectiveWhen) OVER (PARTITION BY WidgitID ORDER BY StartEffectiveWhen ASC) AS LagEndEffectiveWhen, 
            WidgetPriceId, WidgitId, Price, StartEffectiveWhen, EndEffectiveWhen
    FROM @WidgetPrice
),
EdgeIdentification AS
(
    -- Create a CTE that will indicate if we have started a new "Group".  The end goal is to flaten down rows with contigous dates.  
    -- This will allow us to reduce the number of rows.
    SELECT  CASE 
                WHEN ISNULL(LagPrice, - 1) != Price OR ISNULL(LagEndEffectiveWhen, '1900-01-01') < DATEADD(day, - 1, StartEffectiveWhen)
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END AS StartingEdge, 
            WidgitId, Price, StartEffectiveWhen, EndEffectiveWhen, LagPrice, LagEndEffectiveWhen
    FROM  ComparableDatesAndPrices
),
EdgeCountsForGrouping AS
(
    -- Make a CTE that sums the Starting Edges.  The goal is to use this to group by.  If the starting edge does
    -- not change, then we are in a common group.
    SELECT  SUM(StartingEdge) OVER (PARTITION BY WidgitId ORDER BY StartEffectiveWhen) AS LeadingCount,
            WidgitId, Price, StartEffectiveWhen, EndEffectiveWhen, StartingEdge, LagPrice, LagEndEffectiveWhen
    FROM    EdgeIdentification  
)
SELECT  WidgitId, Price, MIN(StartEffectiveWhen) AS StartEffectiveWhen, MAX(EndEffectiveWhen) AS EndEffectiveWhen 
FROM    EdgeCountsForGrouping
GROUP BY Price, WidgitID, LeadingCount
```